# OpenLayers 3 not displayed layer

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Why my "OpenLayers" not displayed added layer?

```
window.setWMS = function( WMSN ){
    window._blockEvents = true;
    var url = WMSN[0];
    var layer = WMSN[1];
    var server = WMSN[2];
    var wms = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
               url: url,
               params: {'LAYERS' : layer },
               serverType: server,
               crossOrigin: ''
           })
       });
    map.addLayer(wms);
    window._blockEvents = false;
 }
```

URL: 'http://mapserver.heller-ig.de/osm/de/technical'
Layer: 'Germany'
Server: 'mapserver'

The layer does not appear.

e.g:
URL: 'http://wms.geo.admin.ch/'
Layer: 'ch.bafu.schutzgebiete-paerke_nationaler_bedeutung'
Server: 'mapserver'

It works flawlessly.

Comment: Can be a lot of things. Give us the complete code or provide us a http://jsfiddle.net/ . It shouldn't be hard to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the default ol map, your map use probably the `EPSG:3857` but your wms doesn't allow this CRS (see `<CRS>`tags in your [GetCapabiltities](http://mapserver.heller-ig.de/osm/de/technical?service=wms&request=getcapabilities&version=1.3.0)). Allow this projection in the layer's definition of your WMS server config and it will work.